# How to replace triple loop with sapply in r

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I read so many posts talking about sapply and nested loops. All the post solved situation like

```
for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 1:10){
    for(k in 1:10){
```

My question is how to solve situation like

```
for(i in 1:10){
  ...
  for(j in 1:10){
     ...
     for(k in 1:10){
        ...
```

This is my example:

```
di<-vector("list",length(rotte_merge2))
od<-vector("list",length(rotte_merge2))
for(i in 1:length(rotte_merge2)){ 
  a<-rotte_merge2[[i]]
  rotte_<-split(a, a$callsign)
  dist_in_km<-matrix(ncol=1, nrow =length(rotte_))
  dist_OD<-matrix(ncol=1, nrow =length(rotte_))
  for(j in 1:length(rotte_)){  
    c<-rotte_[j] 
    c<-data.frame(c)
    colnames(c)<-c("time","lat","lon","callsign","OR","DE","ICAOType","merge","count")
    g<-length(c$lat)
    c<-c[order(c$time),]
    plot(c$lat,c$lon)
      d <- sapply(2:(nrow(c)-1), function(x) distGeo(cbind(c$lon[x],c$lat[x]),cbind(c$lon[x-1],c$lat[x-1]))/1000);
      d[1]<- distGeo(cbind(c$lon[g-1], c$lat[g-1]),cbind(c$lon[1], c$lat[1]))/1000
      d[2]<-distGeo(cbind(c$lon[2], c$lat[2]),cbind(c$lon[g], c$lat[g]))/1000
    max_dist<-which.max(d)
    dist_in_km[j,1]<-d[max_dist] 
    dist_OD[j,1]<-distGeo(cbind(c$lon[length(c$lat)], c$lat[length(c$lat)]),cbind(c$lon[1], c$lat[1]))/1000 
  }
  di[[i]]<-dist_in_km
  od[[i]]<-dist_OD
  print(i)
  flush.console()
}
```

where rotte_merge2 is a list of matrices.

Thank you very much.

EDIT
In my example I have a list of matrices. Matrices are a collection of coordinates. First step is split matrices in list and I want to calculate de distance between a point and his successor in every list.
So, the first loop is to roll by matrices, the second loop is to roll by list(created by splitting matrices) and the last loop is to roll by every coordinates.

matrices (rotte_merge2) are like

```
 time      lat           lon       callsign OR   DE ICAOType     merge
1504252229 50.84889   4.359764500   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252244 63.99482 -22.623094412   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252259 63.99482 -22.622935955   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252274 63.99482 -22.622883136   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252289 63.99482 -22.622883136   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252304 63.99482 -22.622883136   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252319 63.99482 -22.622883136   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252334 63.99482 -22.622883136   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504252349 63.99429 -22.620437622   ICE554 BIKF EBBR     B752 BIKF EBBR
1504256579 53.58838   0.2505852     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256594 53.57529   0.2985927     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256609 53.56174   0.3477958     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256624 53.54768   0.3973912     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256639 53.53391   0.4438477     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256654 53.51857   0.4946202     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256669 53.50456   0.5407628     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
1504256684 53.49006   0.5888187     WOW462 BIKF EBBR     A321 BIKF EBBR
```

lists are made splitting matrix by callsign (in this case 2 lists)

Comment: What's probably going to be neater is mapping over all combinations with `purrr`, but example data helps more than the blob of code you've added.
So you will be more likely to get an answer with some example code and the intended output described.

Comment: I have added some details. Meanwhile thank you for your answer.